# Django is_staff: when User registered he is staff but not have any Permissions i want when he register he will get all Permissions by default

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

hare i do the save what i need to add for he will get all Permissions by default

```
myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1,is_staff=True)
        myuser.first_name = fname
        myuser.last_name = lname
        myuser.is_active = False
        myuser.save()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look into Django `models.User` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model).

I case if you *really* want to give User all permissions you can make him `superuser`.

> is_superuser
>
> Boolean. Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.

Comment: it still dont working ho the code need to be ?